# unknow query after flushing with doctrine and fosrestbundle in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

thank you in advanc for helping me , it's been a week i'm stuck with an unknow behavior of doctrine and fosrestbundle in symfony.

i have 2 entities with a many to many relationship : product and categories

everything worked fine since last week when i sent a patch request on the productRESTcontroller to update the relations between entities , after flushing , normally it retuns me the updated entity. 
but now , it updated the entity but it also makes a lot of "SELECT" queries, that i've never made.

- request is created and executed with guzzle, it's a promise ( asynchronuous request )
- productRESTcontroller is created with voryxRestGeneratorBundle working with fosrestbundle and jmsserializerbundle

i deleted doctrine cache , symfony cache etc , tries many other ways to update the entity but nothing resolved that issue.

i can see that in log :

```
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE Category SET name = ? WHERE id = ? ["EXPRESS",10152] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_prod_dist AS id_prod_dist2, t0.ref_prod AS ref_prod3, t0.on_sale AS on_sale4, t0.price AS price5, t0.ecotax AS ecotax6, t0.ean13 AS ean137, t0.active AS active8, t0.id_default_image AS id_default_image9, t0.name AS name10, t0.id_cats AS id_cats11, t0.id_combis AS id_combis12, t0.link_rewrite AS link_rewrite13, t0.weight_product AS weight_product14, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto15 FROM Product t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = ? [10152] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [14] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_prod_dist AS id_prod_dist2, t0.ref_prod AS ref_prod3, t0.on_sale AS on_sale4, t0.price AS price5, t0.ecotax AS ecotax6, t0.ean13 AS ean137, t0.active AS active8, t0.id_default_image AS id_default_image9, t0.name AS name10, t0.id_cats AS id_cats11, t0.id_combis AS id_combis12, t0.link_rewrite AS link_rewrite13, t0.weight_product AS weight_product14, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto15 FROM Product t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = ? [10180] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [12] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_prod_dist AS id_prod_dist2, t0.ref_prod AS ref_prod3, t0.on_sale AS on_sale4, t0.price AS price5, t0.ecotax AS ecotax6, t0.ean13 AS ean137, t0.active AS active8, t0.id_default_image AS id_default_image9, t0.name AS name10, t0.id_cats AS id_cats11, t0.id_combis AS id_combis12, t0.link_rewrite AS link_rewrite13, t0.weight_product AS weight_product14, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto15 FROM Product t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = ? [10186] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [13] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_prod_dist AS id_prod_dist2, t0.ref_prod AS ref_prod3, t0.on_sale AS on_sale4, t0.price AS price5, t0.ecotax AS ecotax6, t0.ean13 AS ean137, t0.active AS active8, t0.id_default_image AS id_default_image9, t0.name AS name10, t0.id_cats AS id_cats11, t0.id_combis AS id_combis12, t0.link_rewrite AS link_rewrite13, t0.weight_product AS weight_product14, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto15 FROM Product t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = ? [10192] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [1] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_prod_dist AS id_prod_dist2, t0.ref_prod AS ref_prod3, t0.on_sale AS on_sale4, t0.price AS price5, t0.ecotax AS ecotax6, t0.ean13 AS ean137, t0.active AS active8, t0.id_default_image AS id_default_image9, t0.name AS name10, t0.id_cats AS id_cats11, t0.id_combis AS id_combis12, t0.link_rewrite AS link_rewrite13, t0.weight_product AS weight_product14, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto15 FROM Product t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.product_id WHERE product_category.category_id = ? [10204] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [11] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.supplier_reference AS supplier_reference2, t0.price AS price3, t0.weight AS weight4, t0.colisage AS colisage5, t0.in_catalog AS in_catalog6, t0.product_id AS product_id7, t0.supplier_id AS supplier_id8 FROM ProductSupplier t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [11] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.refCombi AS refCombi2, t0.idProdAttrDist AS idProdAttrDist3, t0.ean13 AS ean134, t0.idProdDist AS idProdDist5, t0.weight AS weight6, t0.price AS price7, t0.ecotax AS ecotax8, t0.majAuto AS majAuto9, t0.erasable AS erasable10, t0.options_ids AS options_ids11, t0.image_ids AS image_ids12, t0.product_id AS product_id13 FROM Combination t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [11] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [17] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.supplier_reference AS supplier_reference2, t0.price AS price3, t0.weight AS weight4, t0.colisage AS colisage5, t0.in_catalog AS in_catalog6, t0.product_id AS product_id7, t0.supplier_id AS supplier_id8 FROM ProductSupplier t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [17] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.refCombi AS refCombi2, t0.idProdAttrDist AS idProdAttrDist3, t0.ean13 AS ean134, t0.idProdDist AS idProdDist5, t0.weight AS weight6, t0.price AS price7, t0.ecotax AS ecotax8, t0.majAuto AS majAuto9, t0.erasable AS erasable10, t0.options_ids AS options_ids11, t0.image_ids AS image_ids12, t0.product_id AS product_id13 FROM Combination t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [17] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [25] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.supplier_reference AS supplier_reference2, t0.price AS price3, t0.weight AS weight4, t0.colisage AS colisage5, t0.in_catalog AS in_catalog6, t0.product_id AS product_id7, t0.supplier_id AS supplier_id8 FROM ProductSupplier t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [25] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.refCombi AS refCombi2, t0.idProdAttrDist AS idProdAttrDist3, t0.ean13 AS ean134, t0.idProdDist AS idProdDist5, t0.weight AS weight6, t0.price AS price7, t0.ecotax AS ecotax8, t0.majAuto AS majAuto9, t0.erasable AS erasable10, t0.options_ids AS options_ids11, t0.image_ids AS image_ids12, t0.product_id AS product_id13 FROM Combination t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [25] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.id_cat_dist AS id_cat_dist2, t0.name AS name3, t0.active AS active4, t0.maj_auto AS maj_auto5, t0.erasable AS erasable6, t0.ids_products AS ids_products7, t0.url_cat AS url_cat8 FROM Category t0 INNER JOIN product_category ON t0.id = product_category.category_id WHERE product_category.product_id = ? [31] []
[2015-11-09 09:26:58] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.supplier_reference AS supplier_reference2, t0.price AS price3, t0.weight AS weight4, t0.colisage AS colisage5, t0.in_catalog AS in_catalog6, t0.product_id AS product_id7, t0.supplier_id AS supplier_id8 FROM ProductSupplier t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ? [31] []
```

and this 6 minutes until i have a critical error message :

```
[2015-11-09 09:32:02] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded {"type":1,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php","line":127,"level":-1,"stack":[]} []
[2015-11-09 09:32:02] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php line 127 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php:127)"} []
```

thank you in advance for your help

Update: i finally understand the problem . as wilt told me , the entity is entirely loaded , and because each categories a related to products and product to categories , there 's a lot of entities loaded each time .

a solution is to put some jmsserialzer annotations specially maxdepth(1) to the joined entities , and specify an exclusion stategy on te related entities , it works prefectly now.

Comment: If I was right it would be great if you accept my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Straight [from the doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html#extra-lazy-associations):

> In many cases associations between entities can get pretty large. Even in a simple scenario like a blog. where posts can be commented, you always have to assume that a post draws hundreds of comments. In Doctrine 2.0 if you accessed an association it would always get loaded completely into memory. This can lead to pretty serious performance problems, if your associations contain several hundreds or thousands of entities.

So if you update a collection in a `ManyToMany` relationship Doctrine will load all the elements in the collection into memory before performing any `remove` or `add` operations.

Marking as `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` will probably not help you here (since you probably do also remove operations).

The best solution I can think of is to split the `ManyToMany` relationship into a `OneToMany` + `ManyToOne` associations with an entity called `ProductCategoryLink` in between:

`Product - ProductCategoryLink - Category`

Adding or removing can then be done by finding the corresponding `ProductCategoryLink` without the need for resolving all the other records (the ones you don't want to change) from your database.